# Error Unhandled exception at 0x76C9FD62 in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x006FF870. occurred

Tags: c++

I try to capitalize every first letter of the words in a sentence.
Can someone explain me why I get some error after inputting word with space ex(asdasd asdasd).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[50];
    char firstLetter;
    int iASCII;
    vector<string> vecString;
    cin.getline(str, 100);
    stringstream ss(str);
    string sIndivWords;
    char cSpace = ' ';

    while (getline(ss, sIndivWords, cSpace))
    {
        vecString.push_back(sIndivWords);
    }

    iASCII = vecString[0].at(0);

    if (iASCII >= 97 && iASCII <= 122)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vecString.size(); i++)
        {
            firstLetter = vecString[i].at(0);
            putchar(toupper(firstLetter));
            for (int j = 1; j < 20;j++)
            {
                cout << vecString[i].at(j);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: `j < 20;` - how do you know each line will have 20 characters? What will happen if a line has ex. 5 characters? Or 50 characters?

Comment: That's the problem with magic numbers that are devoid of any magic.  You probably would not have made this mistake if you would have picked a better name for the variable.  Ought to be vecWords.

Comment: no i just tested because before it was vecString.size() but it only output 2 letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated in their comments, your (non-)magic number of `20` is the problem, here:

```
for (int j = 1; j < 20;j++) {
    cout << vecString[i].at(j);
}
```

This will crash when `vecString[i]` has less than 20 characters!

Try using something more appropriate, like:

```
for (int j = 1; j < vecString[i].length(); j++) {
    cout << vecString[i].at(j);
}
```

*As a side note, your attempt to use `vecString.size()` will fail, because that gives you the number of separate strings, not the length of any one string.*